# My HTML code is not working as the source code

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML & CSS from a video step-by-step. In the beginning, we should make a header.
But I don't why the code is not working the same.

The problem is the header must be full width but in my case, it's not. It only became full width when I **remove** "**max-width: 100%**" from the **.col** class

[image]

[image]

here is my code:

```css
/* app.css */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.body {
  font-family: "Nunito Regulsr";
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}


/* grid.css */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 576px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 992px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  max-width: 100% flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: max-width means your div width won't be bigger than 100% in this situation, you have to use this property when you want your div to not be bigger then a specific width, in your case you have to use the "width: 100%;" not max-width, it's like you have a bag full of 50 stuffs (the width is 50%) and this bag can't contain more than 100 stuffs (max-width)

Comment: To explain a bit more: your `.row`s are using the [flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#properties_applied_to_flex_items), in which children initially have their (horizontal) size defined by `width`, which initially is `auto`, meaning it is determined by the contents of the child. `flex-grow` will allow flex-items (the children) to grow into the remaining available space of their parent. Since you forgot the `;` after the `max-width`, your `flex-grow` is not interpreted as a CSS declaration.